# dsaSign and doesn't work with private key

Tags: javascript, dsa

I am using the license generator of [FastSpring](https://fastspring.com/) and their documentation is very poor, especially on the JavaScript functions `dsaSign(arg1, arg2)` with the following explanation:

**dsaSign(arg1, arg2)**:

> arg1 is a 512 or 1024 byte DSA key in PEM format. arg2 is the String to sign. Returns a Base64 String.

I visisted https://8gwifi.org/dsafunctions.jsp to create a test DSA 1024 private key, **for example**:

```
-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBuwIBAAKBgQC+4a7B9iSKIW262/R/2+St9j1CWoyWXEAHphzSFXSVNbSPWUvW
bsX43B6wFW+r1bSOU9bNnArvh8PZnRWC9+kg+WbXoJPIbpkU/rjA4D9VkrcI3HcH
VlbNDGxCbue8MpLPOks8QMzY+eaNI+Uvwpf5fdSR+AfEIitcL51alWXrzwIVAMc1
fiVC76ZinbyCC5+o6nZBx6SVAoGABmXB1tE2dZy2Ck9d64rljX293OQianF6ZH/V
zNND8KPhq+NnMF3X7hC+39MF9/KSitvuTK3tlj9zuPZlooKQSGjlUSxWIDWYz1/W
Ogt5/rxS3CGlu8NIXd2IFIaiQJq8vAoTD+wYqPPZn6UkEwwD3Zqnk9f/KDz3LW3P
HQd0yekCgYBHn8n0MYPK3NzNk05SsiXsz4GZhNvU/Q0MqP9fF7fmNCS2e4Ri4LJI
qFg65dpkB0BKhnuEwN26QipGnY952gBOf9ut4HBoTGIu+uK1ae2cf5V2BmR0/ZV6
V1Aui3hZ65/itto9P3waSciyD2Mtql7G11DQIgjyJ/g+hv9Os+14TwIVAJKBsT8T
Pj2rxwbMOOBerrI2w+L3
-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Here is my example code:

```
var key = "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";
var license = dsaSign(key, "Foo");
```

And I receive with no further explanation:

```
-- ERROR --
Script is invalid 
Error :Wrapped java.lang.RuntimeException: DSA sign error: null (#3)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

its happened to me, im not sure but i think i added the key with the start/end lines and for some strange reason it's worked.

```
var key = "-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY----- your code -----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give it a try and accept if the answer works